# List all items (folders and files) from a storage

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to list all the items and subitems from a OneDrive drive with O365 python library.

My OneDrive is organized as followed:

```
1:F: Clt
1:F: CltRoot
1:F: Documents
--2:F:clientDocs
--2:F:clt
---3:F:sub3
1:F: ID-Clt-Ctr
--2:F:Clt
---3:F:Clt
----4:F:Sub4
--2:F:Pieces
1:F: Pictures
1:f: Clt.txt
1:f: Getting started with OneDrive.pdf
1:f: text2.txt
```

f for file and F for Folder and the number is the depth level

with this code I can list until a fixed sub level, which is 3

```
# 3 levels
items = my_drive.get_items() 
for item in items: 
    if (item.is_folder) : 
        print('1:F:',item.name) 
        for si in item.get_child_folders(): 
            if  (si.is_folder):
                print('2:F:'+si.name)
                for ssi in si.get_child_folders(): 
                    if  (ssi.is_folder):
                        print('3:F:'+ssi.name)
                    elif (ssi.is_file) :
                        print('3:f:',ssi.name)  
            elif (si.is_file) :
                print('2:f:',si.name)                  
    elif (item.is_file) :
        print('1:f:',item.name)
```

I would like to be able to have a code which will continue to display file or folder with no sub level limit (sub4 is not displayed), the condition to continue is to test if the item is a folder and content a children folder via item.get_child_folders()

How can I do that, please?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It is not clear what class the `my_drive` is (or even what library do you use). If this is on disk, then I suggest to use of `os.walk`. If not, and you want to traverse the online onedrive through some api, then, make it a recursive function (when item is folder call itself with the item as the directory root)

Comment: Hi i am using python o365 library, My question is more related to how I can use a while there is still a child folder please continue to print and go to the subfolder to continue to print... Is it a better explanation ?

Comment: I put much more details to be more precise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code to get you started. (The code calls are copied from your code and I assume that they are correct). This should work, albeit it wont print out the directory levels (I'll leave that functionality for you to implement).

```
def print_dir(items):
  for item in items:
    print(item.name)
    if item.is_dir:
      # do stuff with directories
      print_dir(item.get_child_folders())     # this is the recursive call (step into dir)
    else:
      # do stuff with files
      pass

print_dir(my_drive.get_items())
```

Comment: Thank Marek, sorry for the late reply